# to change text position

Tags: java, android, eclipse

my code is to change the position of textView .. i searched for it in search engine and i found the following code and it work correctly when i wrote it on .java .

my question is what the logic of this code ..what the logic of using 3/2 and 1/2  . 
why use 3/2 ?

```
     tvView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0 , MotionEvent arg1) {
            switch (arg1.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : 
                moving = true ; 
                break ; 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE : 
                if (moving) 
                {
                    x = arg1.getRawX()- tvView.getWidth()/2  ; 
                    y = arg1.getRawY() - tvView.getHeight() * 3/2 ; 
                    tvView.setX(x) ; 
                    tvView.setY(y) ; 

                }
                break ; 

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP : 
            moving = false ; 
                break ; 
            }
    return true;
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the /2 makes it so that where you touch the screen it will move the CENTER of the text there, because its the length of the text divided by 2. As for the 3/2, I'm assuming that its to put the text a little bit lower then where you are touching? Because it is multiplying the y position by 3/2 of its length. I'm assuming it does this so that you can see exactly where you are moving the text.